# How to connect to mongoDs-Atlas in a nodejs app?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I am trying to connect to my mongoDb-Atlas from my node.js app

this is my code:

```js
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const assert = require('assert');
const url = 'mongodb://username:<password>@cluster0-shard-00-00-afixn.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-afixn.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-afixn.mongodb.net:27017/Yarden?ssl=true&replicaSet=Cluster0-shard-0&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true';
const client = new MongoClient(url);
client.connect(function(err) {
  assert.equal(null, err);
  console.log("Connected successfully to server");
  client.close();
});
```

The error I get:

> AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: null == [AssertionError
>   [ERR_ASSERTION]: null == Error: Password contains an illegal unescaped
>   character] {
>       at parseConnectionString (/Users/admin/Desktop/node/node_modules/mongodb/lib/url_parser.js:298:13)
>       at parseHandler (/Users/admin/Desktop/node/node_modules/mongodb/lib/url_parser.js:129:14)
>       at module.exports (/Users/admin/Desktop/node/node_modules/mongodb/lib/url_parser.js:25:12)
>       at deprecated (internal/util.js:67:15)
>       at connect (/Users/admin/Desktop/node/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operati...
>       at /Users/admin/Desktop/node/index.js:64:10
>       at err (/Users/admin/Desktop/node/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:411:14)
>       at executeCallback (/Users/admin/Desktop/node/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:401:25)
>       at executeOperation (/Users/admin/Desktop/node/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:418:7)
>       at MongoClient.connect (/Users/admin/Desktop/node/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:175:10)
>       at Object. (/Users/admin/Desktop/node/index.js:63:8)
>       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:707:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:718:10)
>       at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:605:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:544:12)

I have tried to change the password several times, it does not contain any special characters.

Answer (score 1):

Your password contains some non-allowed characters on URLs try to escape it with  `uri_decode_auth: true`

```
mongoClient.connect("mongodb://username:p%40ssword@host:port/dbname", { 
    uri_decode_auth: true 
    }, function(err, db) {

    }
);
```

OR like this :

```
const dbUrl = `mongodb://username:${encodeURIComponent('@Password')}@localhost:27017/mydb`;
```

Comment: As I already mentioned in the question, my password doesn't contain any special characters

Comment: The username or the password: you can read the error message again `Password contains an illegal unescaped character`

Answer (score 0):

add user to mongodb and replace  username : with your  user username and password with user password!

```html
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const assert = require('assert');
const url = 'mongodb://your username:<your password>@cluster0-shard-00-00-afixn.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-afixn.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-afixn.mongodb.net:27017/Yarden?ssl=true&replicaSet=Cluster0-shard-0&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true';
const client = new MongoClient(url);
client.connect(function(err) {
  assert.equal(null, err);
  console.log("Connected successfully to server");
  client.close();
});
```

Comment: Did that, here I wrote username and password to not specify mine